# Comparing Coefficients for Partial Fractions

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, partial-fractions

See this simple example :

$$\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x-2)}\equiv \frac{A}{(x-1)}+\frac{B}{(x-2)}$$

Then we can get

$x+1 \equiv A(x-2)+B(x-1)$ for $x \neq 1 ,2$

My Question :

Is it correct to put $x=1$ to find $A$ ,
Is it correct to put $x=2$ to find $B$, other than comparing coefficients ?

Both methods give the same answer. But we get $x+1 \equiv A(x-2)+B(x-1)$ for $x \neq 1 ,2$ . So is it okay if I use $x=1$ to find $A$ ?

Comment: This is **the** trick to use, for sure !

Comment: @AngeloMark Yes.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in using this trick...

Comment: It is perfectly correct, and I'll it's recommended to find them this way. The justification is that if two polynomials of degree $< n$ are equal for $n$ values of $x$, or more, the polynomials are equal.

Comment: But we get $x+1 \equiv A(x-2)+B(x-1)$ for $x \neq 1 ,2$ . THen again we put $x=1$ . That is what bothers me. Any explanation for "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's okay! You can either substitute by a value (here 1 and 2 are called two poles) or you can identify the coefficients or even take the limit etc...

Comment: But we get $x+1≡A(x−2)+B(x−1)$ for $x≠1,2$ . Then again we put $x=1$ . That is what bothers me. Any explanation for "Yes"

Comment: Yes because even for $x\ne1$ the limit $\lim_{x\to1}$ is allowed and this limit is nothing but the substituting by 1 due to the continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to do that.  Notice that while the fractions are not defined at x= 1 or x= 2, once you have multiplied by (x- 1)(x- 2) those fractions are no longer a problem.  If you set x= 1, 1+ 1= 2= A(1- 2)+ B(0) or 2= -A so A= -2.  If you set x= 2, you get 2+ 1= 3= A(0)+ B(2- 1) or 3= B.

Another thing you can do is actually get "common denominators" on the right and add the fractions: $\frac{A}{x- 1}+ \frac{B}{x- 2}= \frac{A(x- 2)}{(x- 1)(x- 2)}+ \frac{B(x-1)}{(x- 1)(x- 2)}= \frac{(A+ B)x+ (-2A- B)}{(x- 1)(x- 2)}= \frac{x+ 1}{(x-1)(x- 2)}$.   Since those fractions have the same denominator, they must have the same numerator: (A+ B)x+ (-2A- B)= x+ 1 for all x.  Since they are equal for all x, the corresponding coefficients must be equal.  That means we must have A+ B= 1 and -2A- B= 1.  Adding the two equations, -A= 2 so A= -2 as before.  And then, -2+ B= 1 so B= 3 as before.